# Keeping TextView visibility (View.INVISIBLE) and Button state (setEnabled(false)) after screen rotation

Tags: android, layout, activity-lifecycle

I have an app with a Button to show the answer of a question asked. And a TextView with a warning text and another empty one that displays the answer when the button is clicked. When the user clicks the button, I want the warning textView to disappear and the button to be "unclickable". I managed to achieve this and everything worked as intended, but the problem occurs when I rotate the screen, nothing stays the same. 
The code below is in onCreate().

```
Button buShowAnswer = findViewById(R.id.buShowAnswer);
TextView tvShownAnswer = findViewById(R.id.tvShownAnswer);
TextView tvWarning = findViewById(R.id.tvWarning);

buShowAnswer.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        String answer;
        if (isAnswerTrue){
            answer = getString(R.string.true_answer);
        }else {
            answer = getString(R.string.false_answer);
        }
        tvWarning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buShowAnswer.setEnabled(false);
        tvShownAnswer.setText(answer);
        cheatState = true;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `onSaveInstanceState` to save the state of your local variable when the screen is rotated, then use the saved value in `onCreate` (which is called upon rotation to create the new rotated activity).

So add this function

```
private boolean cheatState = false;
private static final String CHEAT_STATE = "CHEAT_STATE";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(CHEAT_STATE, cheatState);

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and in your `onCreate` you can then call

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    cheatState = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CHEAT_STATE);
    if( cheatState ) {
        buShowAnswer.setEnabled(false);
        tvWarning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it answers your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow, I didn't know anything about accepting an answer. However, I did it it now. thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You can go with navylover or you do the following

1. Open your manifest file
2. add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to your activity like

   <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:configChanges = "keyboard|orientation|screenSize"
   //and leave the rest of the code of your activity as it is. Just add this line and you are good to go

What Happen when you rotate your screen? actually your activity configuration changes and you may say your activity is created as new again. When you rotate your screen it actually destroy your activity and recreate it and everything reset back.
But this is not a best option to use this line of code. you can use viewModal. it saves your avtivity state and when your activity destroyed and recreated then the same viewModal Linked with that activity which helps in saving configuration and saving states

Hope this is Helping

Answer (score 0):

Oncreate() callback will be triggered when screen rotates, add below line in Androidmanifest.xml to prevent recreate activity.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize
```

The detailed explantion is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

Comment: This is somewhat dirty workaround - view state will still be lost when activity goes into background and gets recreated. Proper way is to use `savedInstanceState`.

Comment: @Pawel I agree with you, the key to solving this problem is understanding of the lifecycle of activity.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Tyler's above, but it saves and restores both visibility and enabled states.

```
private boolean isAnswerEnabled; 
private int warningTextVisibility;
private static final String STATE_ANSWER = "state_cheat";
private static final String STATE_WARNING_VISIBILITY = "state_warning_visibility"

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_ANSWER, isAnswerEnabled);
    oustState.putInt(STATE_WARNING_VISIBILITY, warningTextVisibility);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isAnswerEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_ANSWER);
        buShowAnswer.setEnabled(isAnswerEnabled);
        warningTextVisibility = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_WARNING_VISIBILITY);
        tvWarning.setVisibility(warningTextVisibility);
    }
}
```